# Simple SQL Query -

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have data in a SQLServer table like this:

```
ID   Name   Year   Value
--   ----   ----   -----
2    Ted    2013   2000
2    Ted    2012   1000
```

I need the view syntax to output this:

```
ID    Name    Yr1    Value1    Yr2    Value2
--    ----    ---    ------    ---    ------ 
2     Ted     2013   2000      2012   1000
```

No cursors if possible.
Any clues would be greatful.

Comment: May be helpful: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Are you going to be limited to two years in your result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server there are several ways that you can get the result.

If you have a limited number of values, then you can easily hard-code the result.  One way you can get the result would be using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select d.id,
  d.name,
  max(case when seq = 1 then year end) year1,
  max(case when seq = 1 then value end) value1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then year end) year2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then value end) value2
from
(
  select id, name, year, value,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by year desc) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by d.id, d.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cd70/10).  If you want to use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function, then I would suggest first *unpivoting* the data in the `year` and `value` columns first.  The process of unpivot converts the multiple columns into multiple rows.  You can use the UNPIVOT function, but in my example I used CROSS APPLY with a UNION ALL query and the code is:

```
select t.id, t.name, 
  col = c.col+cast(seq as varchar(4)), 
  c.val
from
(
  select id, name, year, value,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by year desc) seq
  from yourtable
) t
cross apply
(
  select 'year', t.year union all
  select 'value', t.value 
) c (col, val)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cd70/11). This converts your multiple columns into a slightly different format with multiple rows:

```
| ID | NAME |    COL |  VAL |
|  2 |  Ted |  year1 | 2013 |
|  2 |  Ted | value1 | 2000 |
|  2 |  Ted |  year2 | 2012 |
|  2 |  Ted | value2 | 1000 |
```

You can then apply the PIVOT function on this to get your final desired result:

```
select id, name, year1, value1, year2, value2
from 
(
  select t.id, t.name, 
    col = c.col+cast(seq as varchar(4)), 
    c.val
  from
  (
    select id, name, year, value,
      row_number() over(partition by id order by year desc) seq
    from yourtable
  ) t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'year', t.year union all
    select 'value', t.value 
  ) c (col, val)
) d
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col in (year1, value1, year2, value2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cd70/13). Finally if you have an unknown number of values that you want to transform from rows into columns, then you can use dynamic SQL inside a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(col+cast(seq as varchar(4))) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by id order by year desc) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) d
                    cross apply 
                    (
                      select 'year', 1 union all
                      select 'value', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by seq, col, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT id, name,' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
               select t.id, t.name, 
                  col = c.col+cast(seq as varchar(4)), 
                  c.val
                from
                (
                  select id, name, year, value,
                    row_number() over(partition by id order by year desc) seq
                  from yourtable
                ) t
                cross apply
                (
                  select ''year'', t.year union all
                  select ''value'', t.value 
                ) c (col, val)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cd70/17). All versions will give a result:

```
| ID | NAME | YEAR1 | VALUE1 | YEAR2 | VALUE2 |
|  2 |  Ted |  2013 |   2000 |  2012 |   1000 |
```